# MYSQL: сформировать запрос для уникальных product_id

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, update, insert

Подскажите, как правильно сформировать запрос в Adminer.php.

Есть таблица БД со след. структурой:

```
Column  Type    Comment

id  int(11) Auto Increment   
product_id  int(11)  
sku_id  int(11) NULL     
feature_id  int(11)  
feature_value_id    int(11)
```

Пример:

```
id  product_id  sku_id  feature_id  feature_value_id

401330  1049672 89719   1397    23078
401329  1049672 89719   1394    24321
401328  1049672 NULL    1394    24320
401289  1049667 NULL    1394    24312
401288  1049667 89707   1397    23078
401287  1049667 89707   1394    24312
```

Необходимо для всех неповторяющихся product_id добавить новую запись с feature_id = 2789 и feature_value_id = 30654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (product_id, feature_id, feature_value_id)
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, 2789, 30654
    FROM table
```